# Evaluate String from database in taglib in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy, taglib, gstring

I have a taglib method and I fetch an object from database with string expressions to evaluate. From the docs, it should be possible to do sth like this:

```
out << "<div id=\"${attrs.book.id}\">"
```

But when I try to do the same for the object fetched from database, the expression between ${} does not get evaluated. I realized that the reason is because I have a String, so I tried to convert it to GString, but without any success.

```
// objectFromDb.content = "<div id=\"${attrs.book.id}\">"
def objectFromDb = fetchObjectFromDb()
def gStringExpression = "${objectFromDb.getContent()}"
out << gStringExpression
```

How can I achieve the evaluation of the expression inside the taglib? I want to have different variables for each object, so to use TemplateEngine is not possible as I don't know which variables will be used.

Comment: Use this code: `out << "<div id=\"${attrs.book.id}\">"` and try to call your taglib like this:
`<yourTaglibNamespace:yourTaglibMethod book="[id:'666']"/>`
What responce do you get?

Comment: I got this: `<div id="666">`

Comment: So the expression does get evaluated. It looks like the problem is in the object from db

Comment: Yes, I also wrote that it could be that the db object contains string which is then not evaluated. The problem is when I convert it to GString, it is also not evaluated.

Comment: I don't understand. "<div id=\"${attrs.book.id}\">" - this is gstring, and it always gets evaluated, no matter what type book.id is.

Comment: Do you mean that the `objectFromDb.getContent()` method returns a string that should get evaluated by the GStringTemplateEngine, but you don't know what binding variables will be needed for that evaluation ?

Comment: @sensei yes, I want to evaluate a String that is returned by `objectFromDb.getContent()`. If it's a normal GString variable created in a taglib method, you can do sth like this `out << "<a href='${g.createLink(sth: sth)}'>link</a>"` and it will evaluate correctly, right? But if it's saved into db and then I get it later, I need to save it as String and then it's returned as String. However it cannot be evaluated anymore since it's just a string.

Comment: @TarasKohut if it's a GString, then it's evaluated correctly. But if I save this GString into database, I need to save it as String since I cannot save GString. Then when I retrieve this saved String back from database, I don't have GString anymore. And it will print `<div id=\"${attrs.book.id}\">` without expression being correctly evaluated.

Comment: Wouldn't it work is you used the template engine's `make()` passing it the current binding ? i.e. `engine.createTemplate(objectFromDb.content).make(this.binding.variables)`

Comment: @sensei what do you mean by this `this.bindin‌​g.variables`? And how can I use other taglibs, e.g. when I want to have `out << "<a href='${g.createLink(sth: sth)}'>link</a>"` in `objectFromDb.content`?

Comment: `this.binding` is an instance of http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Binding.html and should contain your unknown variable (otherwise we need to know where you get it from). Since `g` is probably one of them, you should be able to use other taglibs closures. But the best way to know for sure is to try. Let me know if it works.

Comment: @sensei unfortunately it's not working. It throws this error: `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: binding for class: my.package.MyTagLib`. Seems like `this.binding` is not available in the taglib.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125858/discussion-between-sensei-and-lojza-ibg).

Comment: Have you seen my latest addition to our chat ?

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
def output = ""
def objectFromDb = fetchObjectFromDb()
def output += objectFromDb.getContent()    // use toString() if needed
out << output
```

Comment: Nope, the `output` is String. And String does not evaluate the expressions.

Comment: I am surprised. I have used this code hundred time without any issues to render stuffs in TagLib and ultimately in GSPs from database. When I didn't use the above mentioned format, I did have issue with evaluating the expressions.